# Where is "Brush Step" in Corel PHOTO-PAINT (to create smooth dotted brush)?

Tags: corel-draw, corel-paint-shop-pro

Is there a "**Brush with Step**" feature in Corel Photo-Paint X6 to create **smooth dotted brush** or maybe there's other method to create this effect on Photo-Paint?

I'm able to create dotted brush using Corel PSP X6, but none exist in Photo-Paint X6 (with the latest update).

---

Here's the screenshot on Corel PSP X6:

[image]

---

But none exist in Corel Photo-Paint X6:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the applications help system or the developer's support channels? This is a tech support question, not a graphics design question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there's no documentation about creating dotted brush using Corel Photo-Paint even after I googling it.

But there's a trick to create dotted brush, here's how to do it:

1. Open **Window > Dockers > Brush Settings** [Ctrl + F8]
2. Select **Paint Tool** [P], select **Quick Doodler**
3. See Brush Settings window and go to **"Dab Attributes" > "Spacing"**, change the value to something larger than > 25  (eg: **150**)
4. Try the brush and it works!